# Django redirect is appending tuple to URL when used reverse

Tags: django, django-urls

When I use `success_url = reverse_lazy('weatherdata:sample-list')`

The URL it redirects to is:

http://localhost:8000/weather/('/weather',)

Instead of the expected:

http://localhost:8000/weather/

For some context. These are my modules:

main/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('weather/', include(('weatherdata.urls', 'weatherdata'), namespace="weatherdata")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

weatherdata/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', WeatherSampleList.as_view(), name='sample-list'),
    path('takesample', WeatherByLocationFormView.as_view(), name='take-sample'),
]
```

And in my weatherdata/views.py

```
class WeatherByLocationFormView(FormView):
    [...]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('weatherdata:sample-list'),
```

Comment: Remove the trailing comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a stray comma in

```
    success_url = reverse_lazy('weatherdata:sample-list'),
```

which is the same as

```
    success_url = (reverse_lazy('weatherdata:sample-list'),)
```

which is the tuple you're seeing.

Make it

```
   success_url = reverse_lazy('weatherdata:sample-list')
```

and you're golden.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it must be something silly, but sometimes you don't see it